# How to mock using Mockito thenAnswer with arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I am using a Retrier class to retry failed tasks. My code looks something like this. I have mocked Retrier class in my testcase using Mockito

```
someMethod() {
 Callable a = new TestingCall()
 Retrier.call(a, arg2, arg3)
 .....
}
```

my test code looks something like this.

```
testMymethod()
 // mock(Retrier.class)
 when(Retrier.call(any(Callable.class), anyObject(), anyObject()).thenAnswer(new  Answer<Boolean>() {
@Override
    public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
      return true;
    }
});
```

But when I run the test, it throws a null pointer Exception in Retrier.call

Retrier.call uses the passed arguments which is coming as null hence the NPE.

> Note: I have tried passing something like this too.
>
> when(Retrier.call(any(Callable.class), any(arg2.Class),
>   any(arg3.Class) where arg2 and arg3 are mocked too.

Any thoughts about this error? Or another way of doing it successfully?

Comment: if `Retrier.call` is a static call, this doesn't work because Mockito does **not** work with static. Also what is `arg2.Class` (uppercase C on class?)

Comment: That was a typo. It is .class(lowercase). It is static. If I change it to non static, will this work?If not ,what is the alternate solution?

Comment: You should post the whole classes (Retrier and the one sporting `someMethod`).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) with Mockito in order to mock the static methods:

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito to have an example.